# Operator overload not working properly

Tags: c++, debugging

I am running into a problem with overloading an operator.

The question that I am being asked to implement in my code:

Eliminate the need for the “friend” access-right in the class by adding a proper accessor method (query) to the class and modifying the operator `+` to use the accessor instead of using the class attributes directly.
Overload operator `+=` again as a helper so the following is possible:
If `“d”` and `“e”` are double variables and `A` is an Account object. 
`d = e += A`;
The Balance or `A` should be added to the value of `“e”` and then the modified value returned

my CPP file:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;

    Account::Account() {
            name_[0] = 0;
            balance_ = 0;
    }
    Account::Account(double balance) {
            name_[0] = 0;
            balance_ = balance;
    }
    Account::Account(const char name[], double balance) {
            strncpy(name_, name, 40);
            name_[40] = 0;
            balance_ = balance;
    }


    void Account::display(bool gotoNewline)const {
            cout << (name_[0] ? name_ : "No Name") << ": $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << balance_;
            if (gotoNewline) cout << endl;
    }

    Account& Account::operator+=(const Account& other) {

            balance_ += other.balance_;
            return *this;
    }

    Account& Account::operator=(const Account& ls) {

            balance_ = ls.balance_;
            strncpy(name_, ls.name_, 40);

                    return *this;

    }

    Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account &two) {
            return Account(one.balance_ + two.balance_);

    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Account& A) {
            A.display(false);
            return os;
    }

    Account& Account::operator=(const char name[]) {
            strncpy(name_, name, 40);

            return *this;
    }

    double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a)
    {
            d += a;
            return d;
    }
```

My HEADER file:

```
#ifndef _ACCOUNT_H__
#define _ACCOUNT_H__
#include <iostream>

    class Account {
            char name_[41];
            double balance_;
    public:
            Account();
            Account(double balance);
            Account(const char name[], double balance = 0.0);
            void display(bool gotoNewline = true)const;

            Account& operator+=(const Account& other);
            Account& operator=(const Account& ls);
            Account& operator=(const char name[]);
            friend Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account &two);

    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& A);
    Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account &two);
    double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a);

#endif
```

The MAIN.CPP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;
void displayABC(const Account& A,
    const Account& B,
    const Account& C) {
    cout << "A: " << A << endl << "B: " << B << endl
            << "C: " << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
}
int main() {
    Account A;
    Account B("Saving", 10000.99);
    Account C("Checking", 100.99);
    Account* AC[3] = { &A, &B, &C };
    double balance = 0;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B + C;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = "Joint";
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B += C;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    A = B += C += 100.01;
    displayABC(A, B, C);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << i + 1 << "- " << (balance += *AC[i]) << endl;
    }
    cout << "Total Balance: " << balance << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When i run it it seems to work properly for the first few outputs, but when it comes to the double operator it stops working. The output is supposed to be:

```
A: Saving: $10302.98
B: Saving: $10302.98
C: Checking: $201.00
--------

1- 10302.98
2- 20605.96
3- 20806.96
Total Balance: 20806.96
```

but never reaches the `"1 - 2- 3- Total Balance:"` line. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Kind of surprised that gives you anything at all. d += a should spin right back around and call operator+=( double, Account &) which is where the code currently is. I'd expect uncontrolled recursion. ah. Just re-read. I think we have your answer.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: Working on that. Have a better explanation in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes. This seems to work.

Account Header "account.hpp"

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

#include <iostream>

class Account {
private:
  char name_[41];
  double balance_;
public:
  Account() : balance_{0} { name_[0] = 0; }
  Account(double balance) : Account() { balance_ = balance; }
  Account(const char* name, double balance);
  void display(std::ostream& os) const;
  Account& operator+=(const Account& other);
  Account& operator=(const char* name);
  double get_balance() const { return balance_; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Account& a);
Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account &two);
double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a);

#endif
```

Account implementation "account.cpp"

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include "account.hpp"

using namespace std;

Account::Account(const char name[], double balance) {
  strncpy(name_, name, 40);
  name_[40] = 0;
  balance_ = balance;
}

void Account::display(ostream& os) const {
  os << (name_[0] ? name_ : "No Name") << ": $" 
     << setprecision(2) << fixed << balance_;
}

Account& Account::operator+=(const Account& other) {
  balance_ += other.get_balance();
  return *this;
}

Account& Account::operator=(const char* name) {
  strncpy(name_, name, 40);
  name_[40] = 0;
  return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Account& a) {
  a.display(os);
  return os;
}

Account operator+(const Account &one, const Account& two) {
  return Account(one.get_balance() + two.get_balance());
}

double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a) {
  d += a.get_balance();
  return d;
}
```

Driver code "main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>

#include "account.hpp"

using namespace std;

void displayABC(const Account& A, 
  const Account& B, 
  const Account& C) {
  cout << "A: " << A << endl << "B: " << B << endl
   << "C: " << C << endl << "--------" << endl;
}

int main() {
  Account A;
  Account B("Saving", 10000.99);
  Account C("Checking", 100.99);
  Account* AC[3] = { &A, &B, &C };
  double balance = 0;
  displayABC(A, B, C);
  A = B + C;
  displayABC(A, B, C);
  A = "Joint";
  displayABC(A, B, C);
  A = B += C;
  displayABC(A, B, C);
  A = B += C += 100.01;
  displayABC(A, B, C);
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << i + 1 << "- " << (balance += *AC[i]) << endl;
  }
  cout << "Total Balance: " << balance << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It sounded like you needed to get rid of the friend +operator function and add an accessor for the balance variable. I also replaced the d+=a with d+=a.get_balance() in the +=operator(double d, const Account& a) function.

Answer (score 0):

In

```
double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a)
{
        d += a;
        return d;
}
```

`d += a;` operates on a `double` and an `Account`. In other words, `double` += `Account`. That needs an operator that looks like

```
double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a)
```

That's right. It calls itself. Uncontrolled, infinite recursion. Eventually, the computer will run out of memory for further calls and something unfortunate will happen.

Solution to this is not to add `double` and `Account` inside the function. This doesn't make much sense to do anyway.

Probably an accidental omission and what OP really meant to do was

```
double operator+=(double& d, const Account& a)
{
    d += a.getBalance();
    return d;
}
```

to add `double` and `double`.

This means OP must implement a `getBalance` method in `Account` as recommended in he assignment specification:

> by adding a proper accessor method (query) to the class